# Firebase Storage user authentication issues when setting request.auth != null rule

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, angularfire

I'm trying to set up a storage in Firebase so users can upload images but I'm running into a problem with authentication. When setting these writing rules it gives me the error: User does not have permission to access.

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
       allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using Angular and Firebase authentication for the user to login. I have user data stored in the local storage of the browser including a valid token. Am I missing something? Is AngularFireStorage supposed to automatically grab the token from the local storage when using the upload method? Or am I supposed to give the AngularFireStorage.upload() method an auth header with a token like with http requests somehow?

I am able to write to the storage if I remove the 'request.auth != null' rule so it's just not authenticating correctly. Authentication for the realtime database is working however, just not for the storage.

The upload code in Angular:

```
pushFileToStorage(fileUpload: FileUpload): Observable<number | undefined> {
    const filePath = `recipes/${this.user.id}/thumbnail`;
    const storageRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
    let uploadTask = this.storage.upload(filePath, fileUpload.file);

    uploadTask
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          storageRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe((downloadURL) => {
            fileUpload.url = downloadURL;
            this.recipesService.updateImageUrl(fileUpload.url);
          });
        })
      )
      .subscribe();

    return uploadTask.percentageChanges();
  }
```

Update: I've found a [blog](https://www.positronx.io/full-angular-firebase-authentication-system/) online where authentication is done differently using AngularFireAuth from the AngularFireAuthModule. Currently I'm doing authentication with [Firebase REST APIs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password). Could this be the reasons why authentication is working for my database but not my storage? I'd like to know for sure before reworking my entire authentication system in my app.

Comment: Quick update for those finding this thread in the future and having the same problem: I've rewritten the authentication using AngularFireAuth instead of manually sending http requests with tokens to the firebase backend and it works! Firebase storage now correctly recognizes the user and I can finally use rules such as request.auth != null.